# How to search a column based on the value of a cell and add the adjacent column value to a list?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to search a column based on a cell and add the adjacent column values to a list.

Example:
Data on a sheet is laid out like this:

[image: **enter image description here**]

When I go to another sheet and select **Henry** or **Ben** from a drop down list the adjacent cell drop downs all the IDS that are related to the names in column A.

Example 2:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [cascading drop down menus](https://www.excelcampus.com/tables/dependent-drop-lists/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that for this answer we use sheet 1.
Sheet 1 structure:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        Dim Lastrow As Long
        Dim cell As Range, rng As Range, rngResults As Range
        Dim strSearch As String, strResults As String

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

            If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("D2")) Is Nothing Then

                strSearch = Target.Value

                Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Lastrow, 1))
                Set rngResults = .Range("E2")

                For Each cell In rng

                    If strSearch = cell.Value Then

                        If IsEmpty(strResults) Then
                            strResults = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                            Debug.Print strResults
                        Else
                            strResults = strResults & "," & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                            Debug.Print strResults

                        End If

                    End If

                Next

                    With rngResults.Validation
                        .Delete
                        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                            Formula1:=strResults
                    End With

            End If

        End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks will try it out and let you know if it works thanks.